# hibernate startup error

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I am getting a weird message printed to standard our when hibernate starts up and i am having trouble diagnosing it.

here is the message that prints out (it shows up red in my eclipse console, so i believe that means it was written to standard error):

```
initialPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 1
maxIdleTime-> coercedPropVal: 1500
maxPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 15
maxStatements-> coercedPropVal: 50
minPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 1
initialPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 1
maxIdleTime-> coercedPropVal: 1500
maxPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 15
maxStatements-> coercedPropVal: 50
minPoolSize-> coercedPropVal: 1
```

there is no error message or anything just that.  here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
    PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- local connection properties -->
    <property name="connection.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        URL...
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">USER_NAME</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">PASSWORD</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1500</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
        org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
    </property>

    <mapping ...>
    <mapping ...>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

despite this error everything does work fine in the project, i would just prefer not to have this random indecipherable text going into my log files.

i have tried searching around but i can't seem to find anything about this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you assume this is an error? It's not - it's the options of the connection pool printed out.

Comment: i assumed it was an error because it was printed to standard error,if its not an error do you know how to suppress it?

Comment: Perhaps grab a newer version of the connection pool (c3p0)